# Replacing the same fragment after Changes in Shared Prefrence

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have Five fragments. Each fragment loads two types of Listviews (Students Lists and Staff Lists). User have to select it from settings(shared preference) which type of Lists they what to see in all the five fragments whether Students list or Staff lists in all five fragment. That works fine.

Now I placed a text(menu item) in my navigation drawer. On clicking that text, (sharedpreference should change) the existing lists should switch from Students to Staff lists or Staff to Students lists.

I tried in some way but after switching the lists my Fragments is not reloading

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position, NavItem item){
        Fragment fragment;
        String switchs = item.getData();
        if(switchs.equals("switch")){

            SharedPreferences sharedPref= getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("switchview", 0);
            String my_view = sharedPref.getString("view", "");
            Log.v("INFO",switchs + my_view);

            switch (my_view){
                case "true" :
                        my_view = "false";
                break;

                case "false" :
                    my_view = "true";
                    break;
            }
            Log.v("INFO","myView" + my_view);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("view", my_view);
            editor.commit();

            // Reload current fragment
            Fragment frg = null;
            frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("main");

            Log.v("INFO","fragment" + frg);
            final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container, frg,"main").commit();

        }else{
        try {
            fragment = item.getFragment().newInstance();
            if (fragment != null) {
                //adding the data
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                String extra = item.getData();
                bundle.putString(DATA, extra);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment,"main").commit();

                setTitle(item.getText());

                if (null != MainActivity.this.getSupportActionBar() && null != MainActivity.this.getSupportActionBar().getCustomView()){
                    MainActivity.this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(
                            ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
                } 

             } else {
                // error in creating fragment
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
             }
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
```

Help me out, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing getSupportFragmentManager() for getFragmentManager() unless you are handling fragments inside of another fragment

Other than that I'm not sure why you want the fragments to reload just to change the content of the ListViews

Comment: Actually my custom adapter inflate two type of list views, Hence after doing this editor.putString("view", my_view); I'm reloading the fragment so that my customadapter changes the listviews accordingly.

Comment: I guessed that but I'm not sure its the best way.

Anyway, change what I said and tell me if it works, I'm kinda new to Android as well but I have worked with this stuff

Comment: no improvement. Fragment is not replacing. frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("main"); returns the Fragment name but some unusual address along with that. V/INFO﹕My_Firstfragment{4272ce28 #1 id=0x7f0b0079 main}

Comment: The code needed to reload the lists is in the onResume() method in the fragments, right? Try adding ft.replace(frg); before ft.replace(R.id.container, frg,"main").commit(); so that method is called.

Comment: well just try, or debug and see whether its executed or not, its that easy

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, to be honest i have no clue bro since im probaby as new to android as you are (im a student and intern), but I can tell that the source of this kind of issues is that your code isnt organized enough so take care of that in the future. If I may ask how did you solve it in the end?